# Pulling from Github to Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, git-pull

I have two branches in a Github repository.
I'd like to pull the code from one of the branches and overwrite the code in Android Studio.

What I've tried:

1. I went to VCS -> Git -> Pull

[image]

2. Click Pull and this is the status after pulling:

[image]

Now, when I check the code in Android Studio, it is still the same. Nothing has been updated.
What am I missing?

Comment: from which branch you want to pull ? master or NavComponentVersion

Comment: well, this is expected since all files are up to date meaning there is no difference from your local and remote repo, if you want to get all branch, use git fetch instead

Comment: @Abdul NavComponentVersion

Comment: @mangkool But the code in the remote repo is different from the local code.

Comment: try git fetch first on your terminal

Comment: @mangkool I tried git fetch on my terminal and then tried to pull again. Same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to fix this somehow.

I tried pulling from my terminal (not the one on Android Studio) like this:

**git pull {repo} {remote-branch}:{local-branch}**

and it said something like this: **"Non-Fast-Forward rejected!"**.

I just added --force at the pull command like so:

**git pull --force {repo} {remote-branch}:{local-branch}**

And it worked.